# Show that the system has a limit cycle

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Show that the system has a limit cycle
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\dot{x}=-y+\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}\big(1-(x^{2}+y^{2})\big)\\\dot{y}=x+\dfrac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\big(1-(x^{2}+y^{2})\big)\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: Do you perchance want $x / (x^2 + y^2)$ in the $\dot x$ equation, or $y / \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ in the $\dot y$ equation, so that there is a certain symmetry?  Just asking . . . Cheers!

Comment: of course, but as I demonstrate analytically

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't understand your comment: do you have $x/(x^2+y^2)$ in the $\dot{x}$ equation? or $y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ in the $\dot{y}$ equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the level sets of $V=x^2+y^2$. Then
$$
\dot V=2\left(\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{V}}+\frac{y^2}V\right)(1-V)
$$
The middle factor is always positive for $V>0$, so that the dynamic of the radius $r=\sqrt V$ is determined by the factor $(1-V)$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose, it did.

This means, there exists some $c$, s.t.
$$x^2 + y^2 = c$$

Then, by differentiating both sides, we get
$$x\dot{x} + y\dot{y} = 0$$

Plug in given equations (presumably the right ones) and see if you can find $c$.

Comment: The question says limit *cycle*, not *circle*, so one might say that $x^2+y^2=c^2$ is an educated guess.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is indeed an educated guess based on the equations and how such problems are constructed :)